# WSO2 Identity Server updating SP/IDP error 6.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I get this error when trying to update my service provider and identity provider.
`Error while updating Service Provider : Invalid application configuration for application: 'test_sp' of tenantDomain: test.com. Federated Identity Provider test_idp is not available in the server. No authenticator have been registered in the authentication flow.`

The identity provider is setup to use a federated saml authenticator. The service provider is linked to use the federation of this identity provider. I can update the service provider and identity provider until I actually login using the federated identity provider. Once I have logged in and completed the authentication process I receive that error and can no longer update the service provider and identity provider until I restart the WSO2 identity server. The authentication process looks like this.
Call service provider using oauth2 -> login to federated idp -> receive saml2 assertion -> send saml2 assertion to /oauth2/token endpoint -> complete authentication.

## Edit

It appears adding this to deployment.toml fixes the issue.

```
[cache.idp_cache_by_name]
enable = false
```

The issue is with the caching mechanism after the IdP has been used to authenticate a user.

Comment: how did you update the application? via REST API or new react console or carbon management console?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna The REST API and the carbon management console.